# MAUI - push notifications support

Tags: .net, push-notification, maui

I couldn't find any documentation of how to implement push notifications in maui. Maybe somebody was able to integrate xamarin library in maui project to accomplish it?

Answer (score 8):

.NET MAUI is still in preview so while "kicking tires" is happening a lot, no one should actually use this in production. Bits are still in progress, as well as documentation and third-party libraries.

Having that said, concepts like push notifications actually won't change that much. Push notifications still happen very much on the platform-specific layer. If you, for instance, follow [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/developer/mobile-apps/notification-hubs-backend-service-xamarin-forms), you'll see that it speaks of a `MainActivity` for Android, that will still be there, although in a different place. Same for the `AppDelegate` in iOS.

You have to translate some concepts to .NET MAUI but it shouldn't be too complicated to figure it out. But if you can't and have time, wait a bit longer the libraries and documentation will catch up!

Comment: Hi Gerald, hasn't it been updated or changed since this solution was suggested?

Comment: Not that I know of

Answer (score 6):

Hopefully the tutorial below will help you to enable **Firebase** Cloud Messaging for .NET **MAUI** project on **iOS** platform.

#### Preparation

I consider you have set up the Apple provisioning profile properly. This means you set up *Certificate*, *Identifier* and *Profile* (especially *Distribution - App Store*) on Apple Developer Site. Do not forget to enable "Push Notification" on *Identifier page* of your application and use the same *Bundle ID* as you are using in your app. On *Keys* page [configure the APN Key](https://www.kodeco.com/20201639-firebase-cloud-messaging-for-ios-push-notifications#toc-anchor-003) - check "Apple Push Notifications service (APNs)" - download it and remember *Key ID*. You will need it in the [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com).

I also consider all preparation work on *Firebase Console* is done according to [tutorial](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7015592#ios) and you have the GoogleService-Info.plist file ready (but not added to your project). Do not forget to [register APNs Authentication Key](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client#upload_your_apns_authentication_key) on page *Project setting*, tab "Cloud Messaging", part "Apple app configuration".

#### Project changes

Having all this done let's open solution with MAUI project in **Visual Studio 2022**. In my case version 17.3.6, .NET SDK 6.0.402, MAUI workload 6.0.541, build server macOS Monterey 12.6 with Xcode 14.0.1.

Check "Target iOS Framework" in project properties is set to "net6.0-ios15.4" and then add nuget package "Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.CloudMessaging" version 8.10.0.2 in traditional way using *Nuget Package Manager*.

You can run into an issue with a long path. Package installation might fail with exception
"System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\...\.nuget\packages\xamarin.firebase.ios.installations\...\FirebaseInstallations-umbrella.h'."
But you can solve it by adding *Nuget.config* file into solution folder with this content:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <config>
    <clear />
    <add key="globalPackagesFolder" value="C:\Nuget" />
  </config>
</configuration>
```

Add *Entitlements.plist* file into Platforms\iOS folder with this content:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>aps-environment</key>
    <string>development</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Add into *Info.plist* file these rows:

```xml
<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
<array>
    <string>remote-notification</string>
</array>
```

You can include generated *GoogleService-Info.plist* by adding these lines into project file:

```xml
<ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)'=='net6.0-ios15.4'">
    <BundleResource Include="Platforms\iOS\GoogleService-Info.plist" />
</ItemGroup>
```

... and let the Firebase package to read settings from it but let's keep it simpler and do not add this file to project.

Instead, change file Platforms\iOS\**AppDelegate.cs** like this:

```cs
using Firebase.CloudMessaging;
using Foundation;
using UIKit;
using UserNotifications;

namespace ...

[Register("AppDelegate")]
public class AppDelegate : MauiUIApplicationDelegate, IUNUserNotificationCenterDelegate, IMessagingDelegate
{
    protected override MauiApp CreateMauiApp() => MauiProgram.CreateMauiApp();

    public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication application, NSDictionary launchOptions)
    {
        ...

        var result = base.FinishedLaunching(application, launchOptions);

        var authOptions = UNAuthorizationOptions.Alert | UNAuthorizationOptions.Badge | UNAuthorizationOptions.Sound;
        UNUserNotificationCenter.Current.RequestAuthorization(authOptions, (granted, error) =>
        {
            this.Log($"RequestAuthorization: {granted}" + (error != null ? $" with error: {error.LocalizedDescription}" : string.Empty));

            if (granted && error == null)
            {
                this.InvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                {
                    UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterForRemoteNotifications();
                    this.InitFirebase();
                });
            }
        });

        return result;
    }

    private void InitFirebase()
    {
        this.Log($"{nameof(this.InitFirebase)}");

        try
        {
            var options = new Firebase.Core.Options("[GOOGLE_APP_ID]", "[GCM_SENDER_ID]");
            options.ApiKey = "[API_KEY]";
            options.ProjectId = "[PROJECT_ID]";
            options.BundleId = "[BUNDLE_ID]";
            options.ClientId = "[CLIENT_ID]";

            Firebase.Core.App.Configure(options);
        }
        catch (Exception x)
        {
            this.Log("Firebase-configure Exception: " + x.Message);
        }

        UNUserNotificationCenter.Current.Delegate = this;

        if (Messaging.SharedInstance != null)
        {
            Messaging.SharedInstance.Delegate = this;
            this.Log("Messaging.SharedInstance SET");
        }
        else
        {
            this.Log("Messaging.SharedInstance IS NULL");
        }
    }

    // indicates that a call to RegisterForRemoteNotifications() failed
    // see developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1622962-application
    [Export("application:didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:")]
    public void FailedToRegisterForRemoteNotifications(UIApplication application, NSError error)
    {
        this.Log($"{nameof(FailedToRegisterForRemoteNotifications)}: {error?.LocalizedDescription}");
    }

    // this callback is called at each app startup
    // it can be called two times:
    //   1. with old token
    //   2. with new token
    // this callback is called whenever a new token is generated during app run
    [Export("messaging:didReceiveRegistrationToken:")]
    public void DidReceiveRegistrationToken(Messaging messaging, string fcmToken)
    {
        this.Log($"{nameof(DidReceiveRegistrationToken)} - Firebase token: {fcmToken}");

        //Utils.RefreshCloudMessagingToken(fcmToken);
    }

    // the message just arrived and will be presented to user
    [Export("userNotificationCenter:willPresentNotification:withCompletionHandler:")]
    public void WillPresentNotification(UNUserNotificationCenter center, UNNotification notification, Action<UNNotificationPresentationOptions> completionHandler)
    {
        var userInfo = notification.Request.Content.UserInfo;

        this.Log($"{nameof(WillPresentNotification)}: " + userInfo);

        // tell the system to display the notification in a standard way
        // or use None to say app handled the notification locally
        completionHandler(UNNotificationPresentationOptions.Alert);
    }

    // user clicked at presented notification
    [Export("userNotificationCenter:didReceiveNotificationResponse:withCompletionHandler:")]
    public void DidReceiveNotificationResponse(UNUserNotificationCenter center, UNNotificationResponse response, Action completionHandler)
    {
        this.Log($"{nameof(DidReceiveNotificationResponse)}: " + response.Notification.Request.Content.UserInfo);
        completionHandler();
    }

    void Log(string msg)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

... and change `Options` values to correct ones from your *GoogleService-Info.plist* file...

#### Build and test

Now, you can build the project!

Beware, Firebase iOS CloudMessaging works **only in Release mode**. In Debug mode `Configure` method fails with message "Could not create an native instance of the type 'Firebase.Core.Options': the native class hasn't been loaded", no matter you test on physical device with properly set manual Provisioning profile. So, we can test messaging using *TestFlight* or *AdHoc* distribution only.

The easiest way for sending test notification messages is to use *Firebase Console*. Just open *Cloud Messaging* item in *Engage* menu and tap "Send your first message" button. Fill in "Notification text" field and tap "Send test message", fill in token in field "Add an FCM registration token" (you got it from log file of your iOS app) and tap "Test" button.

#### Recommended links

- [FirebasePushNotificationPlugin - Firebase Setup](https://github.com/CrossGeeks/FirebasePushNotificationPlugin/blob/master/docs/FirebaseSetup.md)
- [GoogleApisForiOSComponents - Firebase Cloud Messaging on iOS](https://github.com/xamarin/GoogleApisForiOSComponents/blob/main/docs/Firebase/CloudMessaging/GettingStarted.md)
- [Plugin.Firebase - Read me](https://github.com/TobiasBuchholz/Plugin.Firebase/blob/master/README.md)
- [FirebasePushNotificationPlugin - Read me](https://github.com/CrossGeeks/FirebasePushNotificationPlugin#readme)

Comment: I have added the nuget.config and all the possible workaround but on my windows 11 machine I still get the could not find path

Answer (score 0):

Previously FirebaseInstanceId was used, but this is deprecated.  So xamarin packages doesn't work.  You can use firebaseadmin, but it's only for sending the messages (fcm).  to get the device id is not possible at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

This very simple example worked perfectly for me. I now have Firebase Push Notifications working in my .Net 8 MAUI app

https://github.com/coop-tim/maui-sample