# Is it possible to install Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.CloudMessaging in a MAUI app?

Tags: .net, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, maui

I am developing a .NET MAUI application for iOS that requires push notifications. As far as I can tell, Firebase Cloud Messaging is the standard way to accomplish this. All of the NuGet packages I have tried to install for Cloud Messaging have given me the following error message:

> Could not find a part of the path C:\Users\user.nuget\packages\xamarin.firebase.ios.installations\8.10.0.3\lib\net6.0-ios15.4\Firebase.Installations.resources\FirebaseInstallations.xcframework\ios-arm64_x86_64-simulator\FirebaseInstallations.framework\Headers\FirebaseInstallations-umbrella.h'.

As far as I can tell, this is the result of a file path longer than NuGet's 260 character limit. How can I circumvent this limitation? Has anyone successfully implemented a push notification solution in MAUI on iOS?

I have tried increasing the maximum path length as described [here](https://github.com/xamarin/GoogleApisForiOSComponents/issues/555). No change. As far as I can tell, Visual Studio uses its own version of NuGet that ignores this.

I have tried using `dotnet add package` in the project directory using PowerShell. This appears to install the package, but Visual studio does not appear to recognize that the package is installed when I attempt to build.

Comment: Here is the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74194855/19335715) about how to enable Firebase Cloud Messaging for .NET MAUI project on iOS platform.

Comment: @GuangyuBai-MSFT That seems to have gotten me much closer than I have before, thank you for that link. I'm assuming this solution is incompatible with Hot Reload, is that a correct assumption?

Comment: No, this sounds more like the issue with a long path in Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.CloudMessaging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is caused by the NuGet long path issue. It can be resolved by adding a Nuget.config file to the solution root with the following contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <config>
        <clear />
        <add key="globalPackagesFolder" value="C:\Nuget" />
    </config>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Hi - added the nugetconfig but still same isue with long path.. on windows 11 and tried all sorts workaround registry stuff etc... but nothing . What Am I missing?

Comment: Are you trying to install this specific package? Perhaps your path is _still_ too long? I  also deleted the cache at the default location, though I'm not sure that was necessary.

Answer (score 0):

As was already mentioned, problem is happening because of exceeding MAX_PATH (260 characters size) of file which is tried to be found. But if mentioned approach do not work try this:

1. Close all visual studio instances.
2. Run PowerShell as Administrator and execute this command

   **New-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem" -Name "LongPathsEnabl
   ed" -Value 1 -PropertyType DWORD -Force**
3. Create a new folder with name "Nugets" in drive C ( C:\Nugets )
4. Again run PowerShell as Administrator and execute following command:

   **[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("NUGET_PACKAGES", "C:\Nugets" ,"Machine")**
5. Delete obj and bin folder of your project
6. Run Visual Studio and Rebuild Project

7.0 DID not worked yet ?

7.1 Close Visual Studio

7.2 Open CMD/PowerShell and navigate to the folder of your project e.g.:
**`cd "C:\Users\Admin\source\repos\MySolution\MyProject"`**
and than run command **`dotnet restore`**

7.3 Open Visual Studio again and build