# Has anyone successfully implemented push notifications in a .NET 7 MAUI application on iOS?

Tags: .net, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, maui

I have seen examples in Xamarin, and in .NET 7 MAUI android, but I have yet to confirm this is actually possible in .NET 7 MAUI on iOS. Can anyone confirm this is possible?

I have tried the following NuGet Packages, with varying degrees of failure:

- [Plugin.FirebasePushNotification](https://github.com/CrossGeeks/FirebasePushNotificationPlugin)
- [Plugin.Firebase](https://github.com/TobiasBuchholz/Plugin.Firebase)
- [Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.CloudMessaging](https://github.com/xamarin/GoogleApisForiOSComponents/tree/main/source/Firebase/CloudMessaging)

The first two fail to install due to Visual Studio's NuGet path length limitation. The last one fails due to an incompatibility that is not yet clear to me.

Comment: I don't mean this the wrong way, but you do realize that NuGets are only things that make your life easier, right? Everything they are doing you can do manually in your app. If a working plugin is not available, that does not mean it's not possible to implement this in your project. To answer the question: yes, I know multiple people and apps that have successfully implemented push notifications on iOS with .NET MAUI.

Comment: @GeraldVersluis No I understand that. The issue is I don't currently have the expertise to implement these things manually. Normally this wouldn't be an issue, but project deadlines don't allow for that much extra effort. I am going slightly insane trying to get this working and mostly wanted a sanity check. I appreciate all of your amazing YouTube content, btw.

Comment: @GeraldVersluis Do you know of any resources that might help me get started implementing this from the ground up? It looks like that may be the only option at this point. And/or do you have any insight into how it has been done previously?

Comment: Looks like this does it for .NET MAUI in a more manual way: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gBbbctEvbOk thanks for the kind words!

Comment: Also I think you can get around the long path error by either enabling long paths in Windows or add the NuGet packages to your csproj manually or through the command-line. You might try that as well

Comment: @GeraldVersluis That's exactly the tutorial I had been following! No dice, unfortunately. I actually did manage to circumvent the long path issue, but am now getting all sorts of build issues. Am I correct to assume Push notifications cannot be used while running an application with Visual Studio's hot reload feature?

Comment: have you tried the nuget command line instead of VS?

Comment: Seems like this Cedric Gabrang has managed to get the Firebase Plugin to work [Firebase Push Notifications in .NET MAUI (iOS)](https://cedricgabrang.medium.com/firebase-push-notifications-in-net-maui-ios-2f4388bf1ac)

Comment: @Jason I have. I managed to Get the packages to install by moving the NuGet Cache. It still will not.

Comment: @PeterWessberg That was the first guide I tried. It is not working with .NET 7. I haven't tried previous .NET versions.

Comment: @GeraldVersluis Do you know of any recent examples for setting up firebase in maui for .net 7? Everything I can find is a year out of date (or target .net 6) and the package combinations / code examples no longer play well together. (as in with the packages we're told to install, the code samples do not work, or the packages cause duplication errors)

Comment: I do not, I'm planning to make some content around push notifications soon though, so I'll look into it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved this issue by targeting .NET 6 instead of .NET 7, and installing Xamarin.iOS.Firebase.CloudMessaging after using [this workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77108140/is-it-possible-to-install-xamarin-firebase-ios-cloudmessaging-in-a-maui-app) to resolve the NuGet long path issue.

Comment: I feel your pain, in the same boat. For both android and ios. Downgrading to .net 6 is not an option for us as we need to move up to .net 8 as soon as its available, since its supposed to resolve the remaining issues we're having with Maui. What a mess

Comment: @Shaboboo Agreed. Unfortunately the built-in maps component only supports .NET 7+, so it looks like it isn't currently possible to have maps _and_ push notifications in a MAUI application without rolling your own solution or using a third party plugin.

Comment: @MasonWay I had some success with this example, though I got stuck on a "FirebaseApp is not initialized" exception. It is .net 7 at least
https://github.com/Xcelerator-Group/dotnet-maui-notifications

Comment: You can enable long paths in Windows 11 and then install Plugin.Firebase to your project using dotnet in the project folder
dotnet add package Plugin.Firebase

Comment: @Sean I tried that. I did get the package to install that way, but ran into another error "Could not find a part of the path ...client_load_reporting_filter.h"

Comment: @Mason - you need to enable long filename support in windows first via group policy and then give it a reboot. I completely gave up on it though as after spending 3 days trying to get this working i found it doesn't support rich push and you need a service extension project which means i'm stuck with Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.CloudMessaging

Answer (score 0):

We are using .NET 7 MAUI and implemented push notifications for Android & iOS with the `Plugin.Firebase.Auth` and `Plugin.Firebase.CloudMessaging` packages.

Follow these instructions: https://github.com/TobiasBuchholz/Plugin.Firebase/blob/development/docs/cloud_messaging.md

But they are a bit outdated, check the updated sample here for the correct implementation https://github.com/andyzukunft/Plugin.Firebase/tree/fcm-demo/sample/Fcm

Use CrossFirebaseCloudMessaging.Current.CheckIfValidAsync(); to check if permission is granted and FCM is correctly configured.Then get the FCM token and test with the Firebase console. After configuring everything, we still didn't receive a notification on iOS. Eventually after re-uploading the APNs Auth Key it started working.

On Android we had the issue that the API key was blocked by Firebase, even with the correct APP/API restrictions. After deleting the API keys and generating a google-services.json a new key is automatically generated that did work. Adding restrictions to those keys did work as expected.